# How to compensate for setInterval timing drift in Javascript audio

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have two instances of setInterval. Each is triggering a different function ( *these two functions are title **quarterNoteFunc** & **eighthNoteFunc*** ) at repeated intervals. The interval for **quarterNoteFunc** is 600 milliseconds. The interval for **eighthNoteFunc** is 300 milliseconds. Both of these functions each trigger a different audio file at repeat intervals hence creating a basic music rhythm. The rhythm between the two function calls eventually "drifts" in Google Chrome making the rhythm between the two sounds dissolve. My question is:

It seems that even though browser based timing is garbage their should be a way to create some kind of "hard" timing reference so that the sounds are locked even if the "global" timing gets offset hence keeping the sounds in sync. I thought assigning the same variable milliseconds (code below) would inhibit this  - but I was wrong.

The (abbreviated) code looks like this

milliseconds = 600;

quarterNote = setInterval(quarterNoteFunc, milliseconds);

eighthNote = setInterval(eighthNoteFunc, milliseconds/2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is to have a single, always active 1/8 note interval, then call the quarter-note every other tick:

```
// wrapped in a closure to allow for a private tickCount variable
// alternatively, you could use a more advanced object with start/stop methods, etc.
(function() {
    var tickCount = 0,
        tick = function() {
            eighthNoteFunc();
            if(tickCount %2 == 0) {
                quarterNoteFunc();
            }
            tickCount++;
        };

    setInterval(tick, 300);
})();
```

This ensures that the methods are always called on the same tick.  You can also expand this to support half notes (`tickCount % 4 == 0`) and whole notes (`tickCount % 8 == 0`).

---

This interested me, so I decided to create a fully-working sample (except, using animated backgrounds instead of audio): http://jsfiddle.net/SycBm/

This allows you to see the eighth-, quarter-, and half- notes ticking in sync, as well as start & stop the timer, and independently enable or disable the notes.

Enjoy!

Comment: I should mention that if you need to be able to start and stop the different notes individually, you can add global "flags" outside the closure.  Example, add `quarterNoteActive = true` and modify the `if` statement to be `if(quarterNoteActive && tickCount % 2 == 0) {...}`.

Comment: I am new to programming so I won't be able to designate this as the "answer" until I'm competent enough to understand it. For now I will simply upvote  - but I am extremely appreciative of this. Thank you so much.